# Crash: Method seems to take 3 arguments but only two were passed

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use a [Unique Object](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/UniqueObject) 'mixin' in my SQL Alchemy project. However, I'm clearly doing something incorrectly because my App is crashing with the following Python error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/user/proj/dir/a/pipelines.py", line 26, in process_item
    deck = self.extract_deck(item['md'], item['sb'], current_session)
  File "/home/user/proj/dir/a/pipelines.py", line 62, in extract_deck
    card = Card.as_unique(session, name=name)
  File "/home/user/proj/dir/unique_mixin.py", line 39, in as_unique
    arg, kw)
  File "/home/user/proj/dir/unique_mixin.py", line 9, in _unique
    key = (cls, hashfunc(*arg, **kw))
TypeError: unique_hash() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Seems like I'm passing less parameters than expected to the `unique_hash` method... but I don't know exactly where the problem lies.

Here's the code I'm using for Uniqueness. It defines a dictionary cache for a given SQLAlchemy Model.

```
def _unique(session, cls, hashfunc, queryfunc, constructor, arg, kw):
    cache = getattr(session, '_unique_cache', None)
    if cache is None:
        session._unique_cache = cache = {}

    key = (cls, hashfunc(*arg, **kw))
    if key in cache:
        return cache[key]
    else:
        with session.no_autoflush:
            q = session.query(cls)
            q = queryfunc(q, *arg, **kw)
            obj = q.first()
        if not obj:
            obj = constructor(*arg, **kw)
            session.add(obj)
        cache[key] = obj
        return obj

class UniqueMixin(object):
    @classmethod
    def unique_hash(cls, *arg, **kw):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @classmethod
    def unique_filter(cls, query, *arg, **kw):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @classmethod
    def as_unique(cls, session, *arg, **kw):
        return _unique(session,
                       cls,
                       cls.unique_hash,
                       cls.unique_filter,
                       cls,
                       arg, kw)
```

Here's how my **Card** Model inherits the functionality.

```
class Card(UniqueMixin, Base):
   __tablename__ = 'cards'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   name = Column(String(50), unique=True)
   cards_deck = relationship("DeckCardCount", back_populates='card', cascade='all, delete-orphan')

   # For uniqueness
   @classmethod
   def unique_hash(cls, query, name):
       return name

   @classmethod
   def unique_filter(cls, query, name):
       return query.filter(Clard.name == name)
```

Here's how I'm trying to query a unique Card.

```
 name = 'Some Unique Name'
 card = Card.as_unique(session, name=name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing `query` to `unique_hash`. Also note that `session` is not part of your `arg` since it was specified separately in the function def. So only one parameter `name` via `kw` is passed to `unique_hash`.

Considering that `query` is not being used in the `unique_hash` function, you can fix this by simply removing it, or making it obscure by using `*arg`:

```
@classmethod
def unique_hash(cls, *arg, name=None):
    return name
```